# Main differences between SNS notifications and Webhooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, webhooks, amazon-sns

What are the main differences between AWS SNS notifications and Webhooks? When would you use one instead of another and why?

Comment: SNS is a message platform.  Web hooks are the concept of specifying callbacks via http POST requests.  SNS supports http endpoints, which I think are pretty much the same as webhooks.  I'm not really familiar with webhooks, and I don't see much returned from searching it or I would be more specific.

Comment: @tster why don't you add your comment as answer?